# What is the longest path in a $3×3×3$ cubic lattice?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

What is the longest path in a $3×3×3$ cubic lattice such that it ends in the center? Consider that such paths must be self-avoiding walks. In other words, we can't travel through nodes already traversed.
By trial and error I tend to obtain 26 possible steps in total but I am not sure how to start to prove this using combinatorics.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect that you are trying to prove that a path with $26$ nodes and $25$ edges is the longest.  You have already found such paths, and the hard part is showing that there cannot be one with $27$ nodes.  To see this, color the nodes red and blue, with the center node red, and alternate colors so that every edge (in this bipartite graph) has one red node and one blue node.  Now there are $13$ red nodes and $14$ blue nodes.  Any path that contains all $27$ nodes must start and end with blue, so such a path cannot start or end at the (red) center node.

Answer (score 3):

As there are $27$ nodes if you prohibit returning to a node there are no paths longer than $26$ steps regardless of where you start or end.

Comment: I think "step" means "node" here.  Otherwise, the center has no significance and the problem is trivial.

Comment: @RobPratt:  I think you are right.  I hadn't realized that when I wrote this.