# Need Help Proving The Impossibility of A Prisoner Problem

Tags: combinatorics, tiling, chessboard

Imagine a prison consisting of 64 cells arranged like the squares of an 8-by-8
chessboard. There are doors between all adjoining cells. A prisoner in one of
the corner cells is told that he will be released, provided he can get into the
diagonally opposite corner cell after passing through every other cell exactly
once. Can the prisoner obtain his freedom?

This problem is provided in Richard A. Brauldi's book on Introductory combinatorics. I took my time tackling the problem on my own. First of all, I tried to solve it, of course. After a few tries I conjectured it to be impossible. Then, I wondered how exactly I could rigorously prove it. The hard part was constructing an appropriate mathematical model of the situation. What comes first to mind is the $8\times8$ chessboard. Since any pathway that the prisoner can take can be represented by perfectly covering the board by dominoes, then the problem can be concluded impossible if there exist no tilings (perfect covers) for the board by dominoes. Unfortunately, there, of course, are perfect covers by dominoes for an $8\times8$ board. This is due to the fact that while all pathways do indeed correspond to a tiling, not all tilings correspond to a path. I then thought of making a model more specific to the problem. If we cut the cell that the prisinor initially begins in, and also the cell that is his final destination. Now, tiling this mutilated board with dominoes is impossible, for each domino will cover $1$ white and $1$ black square; if we cut two squares diagonally opposite each other, we will have cut 2 squares of the same color, and hence have $32$ black and $30$ white squares. This unevenness deems it impossible for dominoes to form a perfect cover.

The only problem in my reasoning is: how do I show that any path the prisoner traces corresponds to a tiling of the mutilated chessboard and that any tiling of the mutilated chessboard corresponds to a path that the prisoner traces? Moreover, how are such problems usually solved? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Passing through every cell exactly once the prisoner will change of cell $64-1=63$ times. That implies that e.g. starting at black he will end on white.

Comment: @JMoravitz That path doesn't end in the diagonally opposite corner. Also [Mutilated checkerboard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutilated_chessboard_problem) is a classic puzzle.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis right, I'm aware of mutilated checkerboards, but did not see any such mutilation here.  As for ending in opposite corner, you are right, my mind did not internalize the parity properly it seems

Comment: After travelling along every domino, the prisoner is on a tile of the same colour.

Comment: @ZoeAllen is that considered obvious, or wouldn't we still need to show why that is indeed true?

Comment: Travelling a domino means passing through two squares. This means going from a black square to a white square and back to a black square (as adjacent squares are opposite colours). That seems obvious enough.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4643328/what-is-the-longest-path-in-a-3%c3%973%c3%973-cubic-lattice/4643335#4643335